# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' python

Tags: python

there are many people who have asked this question but i am a noob at computer programming and cant understand the complicated stuff so i need the answer somewhat dumb down  i keep getting the same error and cant correct it

```
   def main():

        #A Basic For loop
        print('I will display the numbers 1 through 5.')
        for num in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
            print (num)

#The Second Counter code
print('I will display the seconds 1 through 61.')
for seconds in range (1, 61):
    print (seconds)

    #The Accumulator code
total = 0
for counter in range (5):
    number = input (' Enter a number: ')
total = total + number
print (number)
print (total)
```

here is the full error code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Lab6-3.py", line 23, in <module>
    total = total + number
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: I think you also have indentation mistake in your code, `total = total + number` should be in loop

Comment: "there are many people who have asked this question" yes their are, and preferred way is to search those Questions and Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you wrote this:

```
for counter in range (5):
    number = input (' Enter a number: ')
total = total + number
```

You probably meant this:

```
for counter in range (5):
    number = input (' Enter a number: ')
    total = total + number
```

To answer your question, `input()` returns a string (like `"52"`), so you need to convert it to an int (like `52`). Fortunately, that's easy in Python:

```
for counter in range (5):
    number = input (' Enter a number: ')
    total = total + int(number)
```

Also, as [PEP 8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id20), you shouldn't put spaces before function parentheses. You should write this instead:

```
for counter in range(5):
    number = input(' Enter a number: ')
    total = total + int(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add an integer(`total`) and string(`number`) at `total = total + number`. You need to convert var `number` to `integer` using `int()` first. Because  `input (' Enter a number: ')` returns a string.

```
number = int(input (' Enter a number: '))
```

Also, your loop should looks like this:

```
for counter in range (5):
    number = int(input (' Enter a number: '))
    total = total + number
```

Total `total = total + number` needs to be inside your loop.

Be careful if the user try to input a string that can be cast to integer, like "ss" for example. I recommend to add a try/catch

```
for counter in range (5):
    try:
        number = int(input (' Enter a number: '))
        total = total + number
    except,ValueError:
        print "You entered a non intenger input"
        # you can break loop or continue
```

Comment: Technically, `int()` is just a function, not a cast.

Comment: @KSFT, levi probably OP getting this exception because he is reading old book (python2.x) and using new compiler (python3.x)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, compiler?

Comment: @volcano yes Python3.x `input()` returns  `string` but not in Python2.x

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Python is technically an interpreter, not a compiler (though it may work as a compiler too)